# Index with switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to combine this code into a switch statement using an index. I'm using this code to allow someone to click on a thumbnail, play that video in the player along with change the title depending on which video is played. Thanks in advance.

```
<script>

// Play the video

$( "#video-1, #item1" ).click(function() {
   flowplayer().play("video1.mp4");
});

$( "#video-2, #item2" ).click(function() {
  flowplayer().play("video2.mp4");
});

$( "#video-3, #item3" ).click(function() {
  flowplayer().play("video3.mp4");
});

$( "#video-4, #item4" ).click(function() {
  flowplayer().play("video4.mp4");
});

$( "#video-5, #item5" ).click(function() {
  flowplayer().play("video5.mp4");
});


// Change title

function changeTitle(name)
{
document.getElementById("show-title").innerHTML = "Now playing " + name;
}


// Add and remove active class

$('#playlist li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});

</script>
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your HTML? i don't think the switch statement is applicable, maybe a _data-_ attribute?

Comment: I have feel that by using classes and custom data-attributes all this could be done in few lines of code... Please setup fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/, if possible, with correct links to test videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to add a common class name to all the items that you want to be video click enabled (all the `#itemX` and `#video-X` elements) so then you can use a very simple piece of javascript for the common click handler.  You then extract the digits out of the click on element's ID value in order to figure out which video to play:

```
$(".videoPlay").click(function {
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    flowplayer().play("video" + num  + ".mp4");
});
```

If you cant add the common class, then you can just list out all the selectors you want included:

```
$("#video-1, #video-2, #video-3, #video-4, #video-5, #item1, #item2, #item3, #item4, #item5").click(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    flowplayer().play("video" + num  + ".mp4");
});
```

Or, if you have no other ids that might get caught up in a partial id match, you can use the starts with selector logic, though I prefer to avoid this because it's not fast for the browser to resolve (it has to look at every single object that has an ID).  I'd perfer listing the actual ids or using a common class name:

```
$("[id^='video-'], [id^='item']").click(function() {
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    flowplayer().play("video" + num  + ".mp4");
});
```

---

If there is no correspondence between the id of the clicked-on item and the video filename, then you need to create some sort of map between the two.  My favorite technique would be to specify a `data-video` custom attribute on the actual element:

```
<div class="videoPlay" data-video="thor.mp4">Click me to Play a Video</div>
```

And, then the JS would be:

```
$(".videoPlay").click(function {
    var fname = $(this).data("video");
    flowplayer().play(fname);
});
```

You can have as many of these HTML elements as you want and just make sure each one specifies the video file you want that element to play and the JS doesn't have to change at all as you add more and more.

Comment: what if each video title doesn't start with "video" then a number? For instance if it's thor.mp4, gravity.mp4, etc?

Comment: @user3349779 - If there's no correspondence between the ID value and the video name, then you have to create some sort of correspondence.  You can use a `data-video="thor.mp4"` attribute on each HTML element to specify the desired video to play or you can create a javascript lookup table that matches id values to file names and use JS to lookup the right filename or there are many other options too.  If there was no match between id and video filename, I'd probably use the `data-video` custom attribute on the HTML element since this is infinitely extensible and makes the HTML self describing.

Comment: @user3349779 - I added an example of using the custom data attribute to specify the video filename to the end of my answer.

Comment: the data-video solution worked out perfect! You're the man! Thank you

Comment: @user3349779 -  since you're new here, I wonder if you understand how StackOverflow is supposed to work? When you get your question answered, you should select the answer that best helped you by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This will reward the person who provided that answer with reputation points and you will also earn some reputation points (which can lead to other privileges on the site) for following the proper procedure and it creates a more valuable site for the long term as a repository of questions and good answers that are marked as so.

Comment: I did not know that. Still learning. Did what you said. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @user3349779 - glad to help.  When you earn a few more reputation points, you can upvote all helpful answers on your questions or others by clicking the up arrow next to an answer).  Both of these actions help the community to see which answers people think are more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$( "[id^='video-'], [id^=item]" ).click(function() {
    var vid = this.id.replace(/(\d)|./g, '$1');
   flowplayer().play("video"+ vid +".mp4");
});
```

Comment: it didn't seem to work for me. I set up a fiddle or what I'm actually trying to do. If you could take a look at it it would be great. Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/zexQa/3/